# How to change example.com/index.php/lib to example.com/lib?

Tags: php, apache, yii

I am working with site which was written on Yii 1.1, web server is apache 2.
Currently I have to resolve following problem:

There are URLs and each of them presents module.
1) example.com/index.php/library
2) example.com/index.php/sys

How can i change those URLs to

1) example.com/library
2) example.com/sys

that is how can i index.php from URL?

thanks !

Answer (score 1):

It is explained in [Yii Framework page in Url Manger](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#hiding-x-23x)

You need to do three things to achieve this in your `apache server`.

1) Enable `url_rewriting` in your `apache conf` file

2) Use this `.htaccess`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

3) config urlmanager in your `main.php`

```
'urlManager' => array(
    'urlFormat' => 'path',
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => array(
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>'),
```

Answer (score 0):

1)at first include this to setting of virtual host:
`AllowOverride All`

2)and add following lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

3) in config/main.php:

```
urlManager'=>array(
'urlFormat'=>'path',
'showScriptName'=>**false**
```